# http-equiv redirect to another html page

Tags: html, meta, http-equiv

I am trying to redirect a user on my html page to another html page automatically after three seconds, and I am trying with this code:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; home.html">
```

However, I get the error that it expected a "u" after ";" (url=...). I am using Atom and w3c-markup. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this. You missed url before using your redirect file

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; URL='home.html'" />
```

You can also do it by adding some script

```
<script>
        var timer = setTimeout(function() {
            window.location='home.html'
        }, 3000);
 </script>
```

Comment: I just tried the code that the guy has posted, and it worked perfectly. Which means that the same can be achieved without adding "URL=".

Comment: Boss, it will also work without using URL , but hr wants to get rid from that error

Comment: I am just trying to ask you that why is it showing that error?

Comment: I have tried url=home.html as well, but for some reason it has not worked. However, it is working now?? Thank you!

Comment: @PranavRustagi as far as I know that is standard using url